# Issue with loading data to an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have made a programme with different classes for the first time ever. Whilst the other methods are working correctly I am having trouble with loading data from a file. (apologies if there is a neater way of showing the code)

I have used 'System.out.println(line)' to check it is reading in the lines and this will output as expected.
EDIT: The question is: the array isn't being updated with each line. If I print the array it shows blank and I can't understand why this is?

This is a class which is called from the main class:

```
private Passenger[] queueArray;

public Queue() {
    end = 0;
    front = 0;
    queueArray = new Passenger[30];
    for (int i = 0; i < queueArray.length; i++) {
        queueArray[i] = new Passenger();
    }

public void display() {
    System.out.println("Queue display: ");
    for (int look = front; look < end; look++) {
        System.out.println(" " + queueArray[look].getName());
    }

}

}
public void loadData() {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Queue.txt"));
            String line;
            int i = 0;
            while (((line = in.readLine()) != null) && i < queueArray.length) {
                System.out.println(line);
                String[] words;
                words = line.split(" ");
                queueArray[i].setName(words[0], words[1]);
                i++;
            }
            in.close();
            System.out.println("Loaded");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Broken");

        }
    }
```

For reference this is the 'setName' method:

```
public void setName(String fName, String sName) {
    firstName = fName;
    surname = sName;
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry... the array isnt being updated with each line. If I print the array it shows blank and I can't understand why this is. (I have made an edit above)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "having trouble with loading data from a file"? Does System.out.println(line) print it fine?

Comment: When you say "print the array", how are you doing that, exactly?

Comment: Yes - System.out.println(line)  will print the file as expected. However the array will remain empty when I try to print that. As far as I can tell there shouldn't be a problem with updating queueArray at each index.

Comment: Your array is initialized in the constructor of `Queue`. How should it be empty? Are you setting the array in another place?

Comment: Sean - the array is printed in a method (called display) using a for loop and a getter. Sorry for not adding this I was trying to streamline my question. The display method works when I haven't loaded the file.

Comment: Do you have empty spaces preceding each line in the file? If so, words[0] and words[1] might be a space, giving you the illusion that what's printed by your loop is empty. If that's the case you'll want to trim the line before splitting it (and split it by \\s+ instead of " ").

Comment: Jagat - there are no empty spaces proceeding. I have even tried it without the 'words'  part in case this was causing the issue and instead tried 'queueArray[i].setName(line, line);' but this also didn't work.

Comment: @George What happens when you print words[0] and words[1] ?

Comment: It will print correctly e.g. "George Harrison" if I use System.out.println(words[0] + " " + words [1]);

Comment: what happens if you try to print the contents of the Passenger at i in the array right after you set the name? can we see your print method for print the contents of your passenger array?

Comment: I have edited the question to show the display method for printing the array

Comment: `end` is initialized as zero.  When is it adjusted to reflect the number of passengers?

Comment: Ahhhh Ian this is the issue! I fear I may have been lost in all the methods I am using. I've just adjusted it so it now works as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change display method to this

```
public void display() {
    System.out.println("Queue display: ");
    for (int look = front; look < queueArray.length; look++) {
        System.out.println(" " + queueArray[look].getName());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `end` and `front` are initialized to zero. 
So it never enters the loop in your `display` method.